# PhD student's authorship - clarifying contributions in publications between two supervisors

Tags: phd, authorship, supervision

As a theoretical physics PhD student, I work under the guidance of both a main supervisor (M-S) and a co-supervisor (C-S) who is based in a different research organization and is consulted occasionally for computational expertise. While my main supervisor is actively involved on a daily basis, I previously encountered a situation during the publication of a paper where my M-S insisted on including my C-S as an author, despite no substantial contribution from the latter. The co-supervisor only reviewed the final draft with comments unrelated to the scientific content. Now, with a new drafted paper that is deemed significant by seasoned professors, I anticipate gaining recognition in the scientific community. Despite my M-S's excitement, I am hesitant to add anyone who hasn't contributed substantially. I prefer to include only my main supervisor as a co-author in this new paper, fearing that discussing this with him will result in a similar insistence on including the co-supervisor, who can not grasp the highly advanced and technical nature of this specific work. I also worry that excluding him may strain our positive working relationship.

I need advice on how to approach this delicate matter and make the best decision for my academic and professional standing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in your junior position you are not well-positioned to battle against longstanding authorship norms, whether or not they are ideal.

The previous example you describe does not sound like the most blatant case of gift authorship; generally I agree with you that it sounds like authorship is not warranted here under the guidelines I am most familiar with, but it's also true that the contribution of C-S was more than *zero*. If there is a spectrum between having extra authors that don't quite deserve it versus omitting authors that do I think the omissions are costlier to academia than the extras.

If you're worried about "diluting" your contribution by including additional authors, I don't think you should be worried about that. At least in my field, the norm would be for you to have the first authorship, and after that it doesn't matter if there are 2 or 3 or 4 or 12 authors, you're still the primary author among collaborators.

I would recommend:

1. preparing the manuscript with authorship assigned as you feel appropriate,
2. if your M-S suggests adding C-S, I would gently express your concerns about including an author who did not contribute substantially to the specific manuscript as well as asking your advisor for advice about how to avoid any possible acrimony,
3. if M-S insists on including C-S, I would at a minimum insist that they also review, edit, and approve the manuscript which I feel is a light ask, and unfortunately even if that situation is not ideal I think you can have a good conscience that you've done the best you can while deferring to your advisor (whose job it is to advise you on academic norms like authorship), and
4. when you have a position of more power in the future (e.g., a tenured position) you can be an advocate for more stringent authorship conventions in your field.

Answer (score 0):

Research is not always about respecting written and unwritten rules, but also about working with people who may not follow these rules. In this case, it depends on what can happen if you don't mention the third author. From the point of view of scientific ethics, you should include only those authors who had some contribution, but from the point of view of the political (or power situation) in your workplace, you have to consider it.

In this case, I would recommend that you discuss it with the supervisor and, based on his reactions, consider whether you can refuse his request. If you are starting with him, it would be a good idea to get to know him more and see if you can afford to have your own will, or if he is an uncompromising superior who will severely punish disobedience. This can never be determined in advance, but his reaction to a discussion on this topic can indicate to you how he would behave. At this point you may help yourself and study personality types - secondary literature is enough. And the same you can discuss this with your C-S.